# Notify specific commenters about edit

Tags: feature-request, edits, notifications

Sometimes an answer ([like this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/111840/what-person-should-i-write-a-penetration-test-report-as/111854#111854)) receives a number of comments of a similar nature and a sensible response is to edit the answer to account for the comments.

If you just edit, the commenters get no notification and more than likely will never see the edit. Of course, it's possible to reply to each comment, "Hey @joe123 - see the edit" - which is OK for one comment, but not really more than that.

It would be useful to have the **option** of notifying commenters about an edit. To be clear, the feature should be opt-in - it should default to notifying no-one. When you make an edit, there is list of commenters below who you can choose to notify. The commenters have already expressed an interest in the question, so it's not particularly spammy for them to receive a notification.

Comment: @JonW - thanks, you're right it is a duplicate. However, that question has not had adequate attention, so I won't click "That solved my problem".

Comment: Whether you agree on the answer given is not important when coming to duplicates. If the question is a duplicate is should be closed. If you disagree, you could place a bounty on the question and hope for an other answer to come in. Or you could provide an answer yourself. (Note that I am the author of the only answer now)